# Python not looping the specified amount of times

Tags: python, for-loop

In a python file I have am trying to write an array to a txt file.
This array is at the moment is 87822 long (but it isn't fixed, depending on the input), each position in the array is a 3 letter piece of text (e.g. `"gtg"`).
I am using the below loop to write all of these to output.txt, but it only prints about 87449 of the items in the array.

```
for i in range(0, len(splitArray)):
        output.write(splitArray[i])
```

When `print(len(splitArray))` is run, it returns `87822`.

I tried replacing the figures with a more simple loop as seen below.

```
for t in range(0, 87822, 1):
    output.write(str(t))
```

This one again only reaches the number `87449`, even when the max of `87822` is increased to `90000`, it still falls short by `912`.

What could be causing this? Is there a cap on for loops so they break before they infinitely loop? Thanks for the help.

Comment: not reproducible

Comment: Is the file being closed after the loop? The writes to the file might be buffered

Comment: No there is not  cap on for loops in python.  The file might be buffered

Comment: try: `output.flush()` or something like that

Comment: It won't fix the problem, but I recommend you get in the habit of using `for item in splitArray:` instead of `for i in range(len(splitArray)):`. It's more pythonic and makes the code easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the help, will test your solutions in a couple hours, no im not closing the file, so that will be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why not this loop? It's better.

```
for item in splitArray:
    output.write(item)
```

Also, do you use output in `with` block?
`with open(out_filename, 'w') as out_file:` is safer way to manage files because it closes them automatically after execution of `with`